# JavaScript Inheritance: "Template Method" Pattern and overriding functions

Tags: javascript, inheritance

## Have a look at this snipped:

There is a *transformator* with a *transformMap()*-method. This method calls two other methods of the transformator: *transformMapHead()* and *transformMapBody()*

### transformator

```
var transformator =
{
    transformMap: function(tree) {
        return transformator.transformMapHead(tree)
              +transformator.transformMapBody(tree.body[0].body) +"}\n";
    },  

    transformMapHead: function(tree) { 
        return "to be done"; 
    },

    transformMapBody: function(tree) { 
        // completly implemented
    },  
    ...
};
```

Ok, fine so far. 
The *transformMapBody()*-method is completly implemented, the *transformMapHead()*-method isn't, this will be done in a child-object.

Now, lets have a look at a more concrete transformator. Here I only want to implement the *transformMapHead()*-method.

But, when I implement the

### concreteTransformator

```
var concreteTransformator = Object.beget(transformator);                            

concreteTransformator.transformMapHead = function(tree)
{
    // my business logic
    console.log("i am the new business logic");
};
```

it doesn't work correctly. Instead of running the *transformMapHead()*-method from the *concreteTransformator*-object, the method from the first *transformator*-object is executed and "to be done" ist printed out.

I can avoid this by copying the *transformMap()*-method from the transformer-object to the *concreteTransformer*-object:

```
concreteTransformator.transformMap =  function(tree) {
    return concreteTransformator.transformMapHead(tree)
          +concreteTransformator.transformMapBody(tree.body[0].body) +"}\n";
};
```

Then, everything runs fine, but this cannot be the way to go?!

At last, the beget-helper-function from Douglas Crockford:

```
if (typeof Object.beget !== 'function') {
Object.beget = function(o) {
    var F = function() {};
    F.prototype = o;
    return new F();
};
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are referencing a specific variable inside `transformMap` (`transformator`), which contains a reference to the original object. To understand the implications, consider what would happen if you did:

```
var foo = transformator;
transformator = null;
foo.transformMap();
```

You would get an error because `transformator` is `null` now and therefore does not have a property `transformMapHead` anymore.

---

You should be using `this` instead:

```
return this.transformMapHead(tree)
       +this.transformMapBody(tree.body[0].body) +"}\n";
```

to refer to the current object.

[Learn more about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: Hi Felix, thanks for your answer. I tried 'this' before. Using "this" results in a TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'transformMapHead'

Comment: How are you calling `transformMap`? It must be `concreteTransformator.transformMap()`. There are other ways to explicitly set what `this` should refer to inside a function, but we would have to know how you call the function in order to give a proper suggestion.

Comment: Mea Culpa! The problem was in the calling-statement, inside the nodejs-exports-beget-aliencode :) Thanks a lot!